# Facebook login C#, get user information give exception

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, authentication

I'm using Facebook to login in a WPF application. When I logging in with my account everything works fine. But when I try with another account I get a exception when trying to get user information. Exception on this code line: dynamic me = FBClient.Get("me");

The exception information: "An exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in Facebook.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: (OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

But I'm guessing I do something wrong with the accestoken..
What I'm a missing here, why can I only get information from my account? Is there something I need to set on the Facebook developer site?

```
private FacebookClient FBClient;        
public static string AccessToken { get; set; }


public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MYAPPID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup").AbsoluteUri);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// On browser navigate. Try to login in user, if success open main window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void WBrowser_OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Uri.ToString().StartsWith("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"))
        {
            WBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            AccessToken = e.Uri.Fragment.Split('&')[0].Replace("#access_token=", "");
            FBClient = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
            FBClient.AppId = "MYAPPID";
            FBClient.AppSecret = "MYAPPSECRET";


            dynamic me = FBClient.Get("me");


            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            User user = null;

            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
            delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                Logic mLogic = new Logic();
                user = mLogic.CheckLogin(me.id.ToString(), me.username.ToString() + "@facebook.com", me.first_name.ToString(), me.last_name.ToString());

            });

            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(me,user);
                    this.Close();
                    main.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error when login in. Please try again.", "Cannot login.");
                }
            });
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();                
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

The code is fine. Problem was that the app was in Sandbox mode. Had to enable it on Facebook developers under Status and Review. Thanks dkozl.

Comment: Is your Facebook app in sandbox mode? If yes, is this user added to developer list for this app?

Comment: Oh stupid me! Thank you, that did it! I'm new with the facebook login, didn't know it were something like sandbox mode.

Comment: You can keep your Facebook app in sandbox mode (hidden) and create test users for your app in Facebook developer tools. They work almost as normal Facebook users so you can create posts, upload photos and albums and so on but you don't affect live users.